# Conditional formatting of a row header based on the values in the column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a table I'm using to list recipes and their ingredients.  Ingredients are rows, recipes are columns, with a column next to the ingredients denoting if that ingredient is in stock.

Like so:

```
Ingredient | Stock | Crab Cakes
===========|=======|============
Crab       |  Yes  | 12 oz
Mayonnaise |  No   | 1/4 cup
Jalapenos  |  Yes  |
Egg        |  Yes  | 1
Water      |  Yes  |
```

What I would like to do is create a conditional format that checks if an all ingredients listed in a row are in stock, and if so, changes the color of the row header.

It feel like it should be fairly simple, but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 2):

Apply to the headers (C1 and the following) conditional formatting based on custom formula

```
 =ISERROR(FILTER($B2:C,$B2:$B<>"Yes",C2:C<>""))
```

Here, `FILTER` selects the rows that satisfy both conditions: igredient is not in stock, and ingredient is used in the recipe. This command returns the error #N/A if no results are found. The command `ISERROR` returns True if its input is an error. As a result, the formula evaluates to True provided that all ingredients used are in stock